# How do I get iCloud Drive to sync again when folders suddenly get duplicated?

Tags: icloud, windows, data-synchronization, folders, file

I've got iCloud Drive on a computer that runs Windows 10. In the beginning all folders from iCloud.com synced to the local iCloud Drive folder. Then, at some point some of the files and folders started to get duplicated by adding a (1) to the end of the folder-name or in front of the extension of the file. Examples are "Downloads", "edited photos" and a file named IMG_5781.jpg. These give duplicate folders "Downloads(1)", "edited photos(1)" and the file IMG_5781(1).jpg.

It seems to me like the original folders and files stopped syncing between the local computer and icloud.com.
On the other hand, adding a folder "b" to the duplicate folder "edited photos(1)" locally show up in the folder "edited photos" on icloud.com.
Files added or modified in these local folders keep saying "Sync pending".

Out of curiosity, I would like to know what could cause such behaviour so that I do not end up doing this again.

But most of all, how do I get iCloud Drive back to syncing?